# Python hash from file not as expected

Tags: python, hash

My problem is the following:
I want to create a little tool in Python that creates hash values for entered text or from files. I've created all necessary things, GUI, option to select between hash functions, everything is fine.

But when I was testing the program, I realized, that the from files generated hashes aren't the same as the ones given by most download pages. I was confused, downloaded  some other hashing tools, they all gave me the same hash as provided on several websites, but my tool always give some other output.

The odd thing is, the hashes generated from "plain text" are in my and in all other tools identical.

The app uses wxPython, but I've extracted my hash function for hash creation from files:

```
import os, hashlib

path = "C:\file.txt"  # Given from some open file dialog, valid file
text = ""

if os.path.isfile(path):
    text_file = open(path, "r")
    text = text_file.read()
    text_file.close()

print hashlib.new("md5", text).hexdigest()  # Could be any hash function
```

Quite simple, but doesn't work as expected.

It seems to work if there's no new line in the file (\n)?
But how to make it work with newline? It's like every file has more than one line.

Comment: It's possibly because you're reading the file in text mode by default, which may result in certain bytes being automatically rewritten, breaking the hash. Try `"rb"` binary mode instead.

Comment: Did you try to print your `text` to the console and look, if there are some strange non-printed characters? (like trailing newline or end-of-file-token, I don't know)

Comment: Yes, I already tried this, it gives me a hash, but anyway not the expected one :(

Comment: @Ilja It doesn't work even if there's just a simple "hi" or "hello world" in the file

Comment: I've tried another thing, it gives the wrong output if there's a new line in the file...

Comment: Why not just `str.rstrip` the newlines?

Comment: Have you tried to strip the newline character? 
`import os, hashlib

path = "C:\file.txt"  # Given from some open file dialog, valid file
text = ""

if os.path.isfile(path):
    text_file = open(path, "r")
    text = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in text_file]
    text = "".join(text);
    text_file.close()

print(text)
print hashlib.new("md5", text).hexdigest();`
If this works for you, then I can add a better formatted version as an answer.

Comment: Did you try @JeremyBanks suggestion? Hashes are typically taken on binary files, not text files where `"\r\n"` is replaced by `"\n"` during read.

Comment: Thanks everyone for help, I like the way it works on SO. And sorry for all the spelling and word mistakes, english is not my native language...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a problem of quoting the backslash character, see https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals.  Use two backslashes to specify the file name.  I would also recommend reading the file in binary mode.  As a precaution, print the length of variable `text` to make sure the file was read.

```
import os, hashlib

path = "C:\\file.txt"  # Given from some open file dialog, valid file
text = ""

if os.path.isfile(path):
    text_file = open(path, "rb")
    text = text_file.read()
    text_file.close()

print len(text)    
print hashlib.new("md5", text).hexdigest()  # Could be any hash function
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I thaught, I've already tried this, but it finally works :)

Answer (score -1):

### Try splitting text update and md5 object creation as below

```
import hashlib;
md5=hashlib.new('md5')
with open(filepath,'rb') as f:
   for line in f:
      md5.update(line)
   return md5.hexdigest()
```

Comment: Can downvoters exaplain why? Doing the update line by line may be overkill but it should produce right hash.

Comment: ...but do make that a `print` instead of a `return`

Comment: @tdelaney There is no explanation given for why splitting it up by line should help, and I don't think it will.

Comment: @JeremyBanks - Its the "rb" that is different than your example. It isn't clear to me whether you've tried that.

Comment: A Direct read() won't fetch entire file in some scenario's where as reading in chunks help. this is one of the approach for reading a file in chunk